# alt attribute returns undefined

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to loop through each thumbnail in a carousel plugin, get the alt attribute for each image, and then append it as a span. Basically adding a caption for each image.

My problem is the alt attribute is always returning undefined..

The markup is like this:

```
<div class="galleria-image">
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Alt caption 1" />
</div>

<div class="galleria-image">
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Alt caption 2" />
</div>

<div class="galleria-image">
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Alt caption 3" />
</div>
```

The script:

```
$(".galleria-image").each(function() {
var thumbN = $(this);
var thumbImgAlt = thumbN.closest('img').attr('alt');
thumbN.append('<span style="color:red;">' + thumbImgAlt + '</span>');
});
```

I've tried lots of different routes but just can't actually get the alt text other than 'undefined' or [object,object]

I'd really appreciate any pointers, thanks so much.

Got a demo here:
http://codepen.io/h0rhay/pen/bDFyt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(".galleria-image").each(function() {
var thumbN = $(this);
var thumbImgAlt = thumbN.find('img').attr('alt');
thumbN.append('<span style="color:red;">' + thumbImgAlt + '</span>');
});
```

Actually .closest() will traverse up the DOM tree to select the matched elements. But in your case, You should use .find() or .children() to achieve your result

Reference : [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/), [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6TvZA/)

Comment: Would you mind explaining what you changed in the code and why?

Answer (score 1):

`closest` looks up the html tree, you want `find` to look for descendants

```
var thumbImgAlt = thumbN.find('img').attr('alt');
```

When in doubt, check jQuery API. Examples are given for every method

**[closest() docs](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)**

**[find() docs](http://api.jquery.com/find/)**

Answer (score 1):

Using `children()` rather than `closest()` works. Since the desired image is a child of the galleria-image div.

```
$(".galleria-image").each(function() {
    var thumbN = $(this);
    var thumbImgAlt = thumbN.children('img').attr('alt');
    thumbN.append('<span style="color:red;">' + thumbImgAlt + '</span>');
});
```

`children()` should also be more efficient since it will only search the `$(this)` div.

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation for closest:

> [**closest**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)
>
> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

You are searching the tree in the wrong direction (up instead of down).

This results in you getting the alt attribute for the first image in a set of zero images.

You want to use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the *descendants* of the div instead of the ancestors.

```
var thumbImgAlt = thumbN.find('img').attr('alt');
```